# Excel VBA to modify word documents with bookmarks

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a problem with my code below. I created an userform in order to generate Word documents automatically which I prepared (I created a bunch of bookmarks).

It works really well on my computer but not on another computer and I really don't understand why. Both computers have the same Office version (1902) and I have activated the Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library reference.

What I mean by "it's not working" it is that the Word document will open but no action will be Performed... And also I have not a single error message.

```
    Private Sub BCO_Click()

        Dim objWord As New Word.Application, wordDoc As Word.Document

'FCO is the userform and the subobjects are combobox entries.
        If FCO.SOCIETENAME <> "" And FCO.NUMCO <> "" And FCO.ComboBox1 <> "" Then

            Dim pathcovierge As String
            Dim pathconew As String

'Path of the files needed there, copy from an existing (pathcovierge) to a new one (pathconex)
            pathcovierge = path & "\Documents_Vierges\" & "CO.docx"
            pathconew = path & "\CO\CO_" & UCase(FCO.SOCIETENAME.Value) & "_" & UCase(FCO.NUMCO.Value) & ".docx"

            If Dir(path & "\CO\", vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir path & "\CO\"

'If file already open, msgbox
            On Error Resume Next

            FileCopy pathcovierge, pathconew

            If Err > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Veuillez fermer CO.docx afin de générer un CO."
            End If



'opening of the new word document

            objWord.Visible = True
            objWord.Documents.Open pathconew

            Dim DocDest As Word.Document
            Set DocDest = GetObject(pathconew)


'THIS IS NOT WORKING.

            DocDest.Bookmarks("WNUMCO").Range.Text = FCO.NUMCO.Value
            DocDest.Bookmarks("WDATECO").Range.Text = FCO.DATECO.Value
            DocDest.Bookmarks("WNOMCLIENT").Range.Text = FCO.SOCIETENAME.Value



'Saving (working)
            DocDest.SaveAs pathconew
            AppActivate ("CO_" & UCase(FCO.SOCIETENAME.Value) & "_" & UCase(FCO.NUMCO.Value) & ".docx")

            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            MsgBox "Veuillez rentrer tous les champs obligatoires (*)"
        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out `On Error Resume Next` - this hides all errors and just jumps to the next line. With that turned off, try running the code again on the machine where it's not working and see if you get errors.

Comment: Also, don't use `Set DocDest = GetObject(pathconew)` This will start up Word again, which isn't what you want. Remove that and instead put the declaration for DocDest before the Open method and use `Set DocDest = objWord.Documents.Open(pathconew)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look in your code and made some changes (also see my comments in the code):

- I enhanced the readability by early exiting the procedure instead of using 'arrow code'.
- Now the opened Word document will be set to the variable immediately.
- Your error handling suppressed all errors. I changed it, but you should add proper error handling though. Think about splitting your procedure in several separate procedures.

This should lead you to your result:

```
Private Sub BCO_Click()
    If FCO.SOCIETENAME = "" Or FCO.NUMCO = "" Or FCO.ComboBox1 = "" Then
        MsgBox "Veuillez rentrer tous les champs obligatoires (*)"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim pathcovierge As String
    pathcovierge = path & "\Documents_Vierges\" & "CO.docx"

    Dim pathconew As String
    pathconew = path & "\CO\CO_" & UCase(FCO.SOCIETENAME.Value) & "_" & UCase(FCO.NUMCO.Value) & ".docx"

    If Dir(path & "\CO\", vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir path & "\CO\"

    'This seems to be the reason why you get no error:
    On Error Resume Next

    FileCopy pathcovierge, pathconew

    If Err > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Veuillez fermer CO.docx afin de générer un CO."
    End If

    'This will let you see a possible error, but you should think about implement a proper error handling though:
    On Error Goto 0

    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Set objWord = New Word.Application
    objWord.Visible = True

    Dim docDest As Word.Document
    'If the problem was to get the handle to the opened document, this should work better:
    Set docDest = objWord.Documents.Open(pathconew)

    docDest.Bookmarks("WNUMCO").Range.Text = FCO.NUMCO.Value
    docDest.Bookmarks("WDATECO").Range.Text = FCO.DATECO.Value
    docDest.Bookmarks("WNOMCLIENT").Range.Text = FCO.SOCIETENAME.Value

    docDest.SaveAs pathconew

    AppActivate ("CO_" & UCase(FCO.SOCIETENAME.Value) & "_" & UCase(FCO.NUMCO.Value) & ".docx")
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh god it was newbie mistake... Thanks a lot, I'll test this on the computer on monday.